# Filenet BPM Webservice receive step design consederations

Tags: filenet-p8, filenet, filenet-process-engine

We are currently designing a web service based process, in which we will be using the web-service invoke and receive steps to communicate with a Microsoft biz-talk server.
Our main concern is that a task on the receive step can wait for some time (up to one week) until the biz-talk responds to us, which (we think) would incur a performance penalty on the workflow system as it will be polling for response.
My question is, is there any known performance considerations for the receive step, specially for leaving work items for extended periods?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, I don't think there will be any undue "overhead".  Yes, internally the process engine "polls".  For just about anything. Including invoking components, or executing timers. But from a system perspective, you're just waiting for a request.

It sounds like a "receive" step is exactly the right solution here.